# Grab filesize and filedate from directory with jQuery, JSON, & PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

After successfully being able to grab the file name from the directory using jQuery, JSON, and PHP, I now need to be able to grab the filesize and filedate from the same directory.

I haven't tried to grab the filesize yet, but here was my attempt to grab the filedate:

```
<?php
include('include/sessions.php'); 

if(isset($_POST['editpartnercode']))
{
   $partnerCode = $_POST['editpartnercode'];
   $bookingNum = $_POST['editbooking'];

   $dir = "D:/CargoDocsPDFs/". $partnerCode . "/" . $bookingNum;

   $ffs = scandir($dir);

   $files = array();

   foreach($ffs as $ff)
   {               
       if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..')
       {   
           array_push($files, $ff, date('F d, Y h:i A', filemtime($dir . '/' . $ff)));
       }
   }
   echo json_encode($files);
}   
?>
```

Here is the jQuery that displays JSON data:

```
$.post('process/displayFiles.php', {editpartnercode:editpartnercode,editbooking:editbooking}, function(data)
{
    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
    $('#allFiles').empty();
    var htmlToInsert = obj.map(function (item)
    {
        if(item !== '..' && item !== '.' && item !== 'Thumbs.db')
        {
            return "<form method='POST'>
              <a href='process/viewFiles.php?img="+item+"&book="+editbooking+"' 
              target='_blank'>"+item+"</a><br/></form>";
        }
    });
    $('#allFiles').html(htmlToInsert);      
});
```

(The file viewFiles.php basically just checks the file types.  I did not think it was necessary to show that code.)

Using the above, the files and date are brought to the screen, however they are all hyperlinks (see image):

[image]

I need the date listed next to the filename and not as a hyperlink.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You want a sub array for each file rather than dump all that into one flat array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Grab filesize and filedate from directory

- [filemtime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php) - file modified time
- [filesize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php) - file size

---

> I need the date listed next to the filename and not as a hyperlink.

**1. In your PHP, change the loop to:**

```
foreach($ffs as $ff)
{
    // backend file rejection rather than client (in JS) side
    if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..' && $ff != 'Thumbs.db')
    {
        $file_dir = $dir."/$ff";

        // Append each file information to multidimensional array
        $files[] = [
            "file_name" => $ff,
            "file_date" => date('F d, Y h:i A', filemtime($file_dir)),
            "file_size" => filesize($file_dir)
        ];
    }
}
```

**2. Immediately inside your `$.post`:**

```
try {
    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
    $('#allFiles').empty();

    const htmlToInsert = obj.map(item =>
        `
            <form method='POST'>
                <a href="process/viewFiles.php?img=${item.file_name}&booking=${editbooking}" target="_blank">
                    ${item.file_name}
                </a>
                <span>${item.file_date}</span>
                <span>${item.file_size}</span>
                <br>
            </form>
        `
    );

    $('#allFiles').html(htmlToInsert);
} catch (e) {
    // Throw JSON.parse exception
}
```

Comment: Although very promising, the files come back as undefined.

Comment: Make sure you still `json_encode` the files when you `echo` them. Can you show the result of `console.log(obj);`?

Comment: I did indeed echo json_encode, after the foreach loop.  The console.log(obj) looks like this:  ["TEST987654.pdf", "December 19, 2018 12:12 PM"]

Comment: Hmm that result would be completely different with my PHP above. Make sure you follow the syntax exactly as is when adding elements to the array. My `console.log(obj);` looks like: `[{file_name: "test.pdf", file_date: "December 19, 2018 08:29 PM", file_size: 426}]`

Comment: Ok, all of the sudden, I can see the file names, not undefined, which is a good thing.  However, the link does not open the file.  The tab opens but I get a 404 error on the page.

Comment: Never mind.  I got it.  Just one last problem... the date is coming back as December 1969 across the board.  Thoughts?

Comment: Oops I actually had used `__DIR__` instead of `$dir` ... I'm thinking the `filemtime` function cannot find the file. Try changing what I changed in my comment.

Comment: Bruh - you're a life saver.  You helped me solve my problem.  Thank you so much for your help.